# How to force STORE (overwrite) to HDFS in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig, hdfs

When developing Pig scripts that use the *STORE* command I have to delete the output directory for every run or the script stops and offers:

```
2012-06-19 19:22:49,680 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 6000: Output Location Validation Failed for: 'hdfs://[server]/user/[user]/foo/bar More info to follow:
Output directory hdfs://[server]/user/[user]/foo/bar already exists
```

So I'm **searching for an in-Pig solution to automatically remove the directory**, also one that doesn't choke if the directory is non-existent at call time.

In the Pig Latin Reference I found the shell command invoker *fs*. Unfortunately the Pig script breaks whenever anything produces an error. So I can't use

```
fs -rmr foo/bar
```

(i. e. remove recursively) since it breaks if the directory doesn't exist. For a moment I thought I may use

```
fs -test -e foo/bar
```

which is a test and shouldn't break or so I thought. However, Pig again interpretes `test`'s return code on a non-existing directory as a failure code and breaks.

There is a [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-259) for the Pig project addressing my problem and suggesting an optional parameter *OVERWRITE* or *FORCE_WRITE* for the *STORE* command. Anyway, I'm using Pig 0.8.1 out of necessity and there is no such parameter.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

At last I found a solution on [grokbase](http://grokbase.com/p/pig/user/122fadn464/fs-rmr-without-error). Since finding the solution took too long I will reproduce it here and add to it.

Suppose you want to store your output using the statement

```
STORE Relation INTO 'foo/bar';
```

Then, in order to delete the directory, you can call at the start of the script

```
rmf foo/bar
```

No ";" or quotations required since it is a shell command.

I cannot reproduce it now but at some point in time I got an error message (something about missing files) where I can only assume that *rmf* interfered with map/reduce. So I recommend putting the call before any relation declaration. After SETs, REGISTERs and defaults should be fine.

Example:

```
SET mapred.fairscheduler.pool 'inhouse';
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar;
%default name 'foobar'
rmf foo/bar
Rel = LOAD 'something.tsv';
STORE Rel INTO 'foo/bar';
```

Comment: Although this is indeed nice, it's not atomic. I would rather do it in three steps: 1) store in 'foobar-tmp' 2)rmf foo/bar 3)mv 'foobar-tmp' to foo/bar

Comment: @MiguelPing: It looks to me like your approach should run into my initial problem but for `foobar-tmp` instead of `foo/bar`. Storing first may also produce that elusive error I tentatively attributed to map/reduce. If your solution works on your side could you turn it into an answer with an example script and provide your pig version number?

Comment: @valid my solution is similar to yours, I just added an extra step to guarantee that if something happens between the `rmf` and the `STORE` (say, exception) you don't lose data. Pig scripts can fail any time, so my solution isn't atomic either, but at least you don't run the risk of losing data.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I was trying to to look for a similar function but somehow, I couldn't locate it in the official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Once you use the fs command, there a lot of ways to do this. For an individual file, I wound up adding this to the beginning of my scripts:

```
-- Delete file (won't work for output, which will be a directory
-- but will work for a file that gets copied or moved during the
-- the script.)
fs -touchz top_100
rm top_100
```

For a directory

```
-- Delete dir
fs -rm -r out
```