# Pig : Load in table, then overwrite that table after transformation

Tags: apache-pig, overwrite

Let's say I have a table:

```
db.table
```

I load the table and do some transforms on it, and, finally, attempt to store it

```
mytable = LOAD 'db.table' USING HCatLoader();

.
.
-- My transforms
.
.

STORE mytable_final INTO 'db.table' USING HCatStorer();
```

But the code complains I'm writing into a table with existing data.

I've looked at this [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-259), which seems to be inactive (I have tried using FORCE and OVERWRITE in several places in the STORE command).

I've also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110403/how-to-force-store-overwrite-to-hdfs-in-pig) SO post, but the author is loading from one location and storing in a different location. If I use what is in that post, the result from the transformation is no data. Deleting the files isn't an option. I'm thinking of storing the files temporarily, but I don't know if this is the best option.

I am trying to get the behavior you get in Hive using INSERT OVERWRITE.

Comment: Why do you say "deleting the files isn't an option"?

Comment: Should have clarified - deleting the files before doing a Store, which forces Pig to execute on the DAG (i.e. the transformation), is not an option. We get nothing as the result if we do that.

Comment: I am facing similar issue I am getting following exception. org.apache.hcatalog.common.HCatException : 2003 : Non-partitioned table already contains data : tablename. When I changed my table to External table exception is gone but script is still failing without any exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with `HCatLoader` and `HCatStorer`.  But if you `LOAD` from and `STORE` to HDFS, Pig provides shell commands that enable you to do the deleting and moving from within your script.

```
STORE A INTO '/this/path/is/temporary';
RMF '/this/path/is/permanent';
MV '/this/path/is/temporary' '/this/path/is/permanent';
```